# Problems in optimizing a function over two variables

Tags: mathematical-optimization, maximum

The following function needs to be maximized over the variable $a1$ and $a2$ in the range $0 \le a1 <1$ and $0\le a2 <1$:

```
fun[θ_, a1_, a2_] = -a2 Log[2] + 
   a1 (1/4 (2 - Cos[2 θ]) Log[1/4 (2 - Cos[2 θ])] + 
      1/4 (2 + Cos[2 θ]) Log[1/4 (2 + Cos[2 θ])]) - (a2/
      2 + 1/4 a1 (2 - Cos[2 θ])) Log[
     1/4 (2 (a1 + a2) - a1 Cos[2 θ])] - (a2/2 + 
      1/4 a1 (2 + Cos[2 θ])) Log[
     1/4 (2 (a1 + a2) + a1 Cos[2 θ])];
```

The following doesn't seem to work:

```
maxfun[θ_] := 
 fun[θ, a1, a2] /. 
  Last[NMaximize[fun[θ, a1, a2], {a1, a2}]]

tabmaxfun = Table[maxfun[θ], {θ, 0, 2 π, 0.01}];
ListLinePlot[tabmaxfun, DataRange -> {0, 1}]
```

Specifically, how to set the ranges of $a1$ and $a2$, and then do the maximization?

Comment: Look at the third syntax pattern in the [documentation of `NMaximize`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/NMaximize.html) to see how to add **constraints**: `NMaximize[{fun[θ, a1, a2], 0 <= a1 < 1, 0 <= a2 < 1}, {a1, a2}]`.

Comment: Tried this. Doesn't  seem to work here!

Comment: *How* does it fail exactly? What errors do you see? Those are critical points you could share with us to help us help you.

Answer (score 1):

```
Clear["Global`*"]

fun[θ_, a1_, a2_] = -a2 Log[2] + 
   a1 (1/4 (2 - Cos[2 θ]) Log[1/4 (2 - Cos[2 θ])] + 
      1/4 (2 + Cos[2 θ]) Log[1/4 (2 + Cos[2 θ])]) - (a2/2 + 
      1/4 a1 (2 - Cos[2 θ])) Log[
     1/4 (2 (a1 + a2) - a1 Cos[2 θ])] - (a2/2 + 
      1/4 a1 (2 + Cos[2 θ])) Log[
     1/4 (2 (a1 + a2) + a1 Cos[2 θ])];
```

[`NMaximize`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/NMaximize.html) or [`NMaxValue`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/NMaxValue.html) accept constraints.

Since `maxfun` uses a numeric technique its arguments should be restricted to numeric values.

```
maxfun[θ_?NumericQ] := 
 NMaxValue[{fun[θ, a1, a2], 0 <= a1 < 1, 0 <= a2 < 1}, {a1, a2}]

data = maxfun /@ Range[0, 2 π, 0.01];

ListLinePlot[data, DataRange -> {0, 1}]
```

[image]